# Plone 5 webDAV uploaded file displays binary content

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

On Plone 5 I try upload the same  file (same pdf renamed )  in the same folder  in 2 ways : via browser and using WebDAV. When trying to view ( /view link )the file uploaded using WebDAV Plone diplays its binary content. Fow webdav access I tested centos davfs and windows network location builtin feature - the same result.
http://pastie.org/10618112
Thank you,
Dan

Comment: It seems a bug to me. Think about filling a ticket there: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/

Comment: it is a bug :https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/1237